# Couldn't Enable Fileinfo Extension through php.ini, still getting './configure' '--disable-fileinfo'

Tags: php, cpanel, fileinfo, vtigercrm

I have installed Vtiger CRM in my client CPanel. On file uploading, Im getting error 
`{"success":false,"error":{"code":"mime_magic or fileinfo extension required.","message":"mime_magic or fileinfo extension required."}}`

so as per some references,i found that need to enable `fileinfo extension` in PHP.
I created a `php.ini` and added this line `extension=php_fileinfo.dll`

But still im getting this line when use `phpinfo()` function.

`'./configure' '--disable-fileinfo'` as `Configure Command` line.

In my Cpanel there is no option for `change the PHP version`.
Please suggest me the best solution..

Answer (score 5):

if you are using Cpanel on Cloudlinux you can enable fileinfo or mime_magic via PHP Selector
https://www.cloudlinux.com/php-selector

Also if you have access to WHM Panel use the following link to install Fileinfo via EasyApache.
https://www.opensource-excellence.com/blog/item/464-how-to-install-fileinfo-in-whm.html

Comment: thanks, i haven't tried but this answer looks promising...